# top users of network bandwidth

Tags: debian, bandwidth, lxc, conntrack

I want to keep my LXC containers light as possible (currently ~400Mb), but sometimes there is a need to pinpoint the culprit of top network bandwidth users (IP's). There are tools like *ntopng* and similar, but i do not want to install them there as it takes extra 140Mb with all deps.

I have 10-15 containers on the server and server itself is diskless. So any extra MB multiplies by container count and eats the memory...

So my question: Is there a way to find *top network bandwidth IP's* by analysing */proc/net/nf_conntrack* (or any other /proc/... magic files :) ) with simple tools like grep, awk, calc, ...

LXC containers runs services like VPN tunnels, squid, StrongSwan and so on.. lets say they are like gateways for those users (IP's) who sometimes abusing those containers.

OS: debian 9

Thanks

PetrasL